# IndexOutOfBoundsException____

Tags: java, mapreduce, indexoutofboundsexception

I did a MapReduce program that joins two tables on a reduce-side. I tried it on small files and it worked. But when I try to execute my program on big files (80GB and 60GB) it fails with IndexOutOfBoundsException at lines:
if (!(fields[8]).equals("")){
     and
parse(record.toString());

```
private String BAN;
    public void parse(String record) {
        String[] fields = record.split("\\|");
            if (fields.length > 100) {
               if (!(fields[0]).equals("")){            
                BAN = fields[0];
               }
            }
            else if(fields.length<40 && fields.length>0){
                if (!(fields[8]).equals("")){
                    System.err.println("element = "+fields[8]);
            }
      } 

    }
    public void parse(Text record) {
        parse(record.toString());
    }

    public String getStationId(){
        return "BAN = "+BAN;

    }
```

I know that this exception means that there isn't 9th element in array, but I don't understand why.. And it's so difficult to debug such program

Help me, please!

Comment: `fields[8]` does not accesses the 8th element. It accesses the `9th element`. Arrays index are `0-based`.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I made a mistake in description. I need 9th element.

Comment: And it's not a main problem because this method works with small files (about 32MB)

Comment: @Tanya is it possible the large files have one record of smaller than 9 fields? could be data entry error/corruption

Answer (score 0):

In followind code snippet

```
        else if(fields.length<40 && fields.length>0){
            if (!(fields[8]).equals("")){
                System.err.println("element = "+fields[8]);
        }
```

If length of fields is say 3 still condition is true and now, you are trying to fetch element at 8th position. than is the reason.

Comment: Use this condition.else if(fields.length<40 && fields.length>8)

Answer (score 0):

Try this to be on the safe side.

```
if (fields.length >8 && !(fields[8]).equals("")){
```

Or as @VallabhPatade suggests, change the previous if to

```
else if(fields.length<40 && fields.length>8){
```

Error out if this is not the case to track down the mischievous record